# EWS Synchronization optimization

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I have an EWS synchronizer for all employees in office which runs automatically every hour or so, and updates all calendars, even if no change/update has happened. Is there any way through the API to make methods/functions that checks if it can register any changes in their calendar, and only update the ones that it registered had changes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Push or Streaming Notifications?

Comment: I looked at it briefly for new mails, but I am looking for a push notification when a calendar has been changed/updated, which I have found no example of.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean by changed/updated, but in addition to subscribing for new emails, you can also specify moved, changed, deleted, etc.